# Is the phrase "produces meaning" valid?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Please consider these sentences:

> The word X produces meaning Y
>   The word X produces meaning Y in sentence Z

Is "produces meaning" valid in that sentence? If so, which seems to be more valid between the both of the above sentences? And if not, may I know why it is not valid?

(the sense intended here is *the **word** X has meaning Y*, not ***sentence*** Z has meaning Y).

Comment: We need more context here. Do you want to convey that when used in sentence Z, the word X *itself* has the meaning Z? Or that *the meaning of the entire sentence Z* is Y if you use the word X? If it's that second case, I'd just point out that sometimes the sentence might have a completely different meaning if you used a different word A instead of X, even though in some *other* sentences it's possible A and X are normally considered to have exactly the same meaning (if you see what I mean! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I am afraid I didn't follow your reasoning. How ever here the focus is the word produces along with meaning. My intention is can I say "The word "X produces meaning Y" when X is used in sentence Z.

Comment: You are simply repeating yourself - which is pointless, since if I didn't understand it the first time, there's no reason I will understand it any better through repetition. I mean - are you trying to say that Y would be the meaning of the word X, or that Y would be the meaning of the sentence Z (when it happens to use the word X instead of some other word)?

Comment: I give up. I've just asked *Do you mean A **or** B?*, and you've answered *"No"*. I shall just upvote all the answers, since they all make sense, even if the question doesn't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My apologies for not being clear. Some internet problems and unnecessary enter key stroke are the culprits here. My intentions A(Y would be the meaning of the word X) and not B

Comment: In that case, tchrist's answer is probably best for your purposes. "Keep it simple", as they say! I'll just edit your question text to reflect your clarification (until it's edited, I can't reverse my downvote reflecting lack of clarity).

Answer (score 3):

No, it really doesn't sound very good to say *produces meaning*.  Just say *means* instead.

Answer (score 3):

Not only doesn't it sound good, but it's untrue.

Meaning is not *"produced"* by words, but rather **interpreted**, by human beings, in context. And human beings don't all interpret things, even words, in the same ways. As should be obvious.

Best not to fool around with "meaning" at all, really. If you want to look up a word in a dictionary, fine. But don't create understanding difficulties you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the word *implies* instead of "produces meaning".